# How to get ACF value inside Gutenberg Block from another page or template? I'm using Timber too

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, block-editor

I'm trying to display on my WORK page a value of a ACF field that lives inside a block in a custom post type project.

If I get all posts using Timber function like this:

```
$posts = Timber::get_posts('post_type=work');
```

I get the result:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(Timber\Post)[1669]
      public 'ImageClass' => string 'Timber\Image' (length=12)
      public 'PostClass' => string 'Timber\Post' (length=11)
      public 'TermClass' => string 'Timber\Term' (length=11)
      public 'object_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
      public 'custom' => 
        array (size=3)
          '_edit_lock' => string '1565259680:1' (length=12)
          '_thumbnail_id' => string '30' (length=2)
          '_wp_old_slug' => string 'harrods-interior' (length=16)
      protected '_content' => null
      protected '_permalink' => null
      protected '_next' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_prev' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_css_class' => null
      public 'id' => int 29
      public 'ID' => int 29
      public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'post_content' => string '<!-- wp:acf/hero-case-study {
    "id": "block_5d4ac446baf60",
    "name": "acf\/hero-case-study",
    "data": {
        "hero_cs_headline": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.",
        "_hero_cs_headline": "field_5d4aa12b9cf8b",
        "headline_cs_text_color": "#ffffff",
        "_headline_cs_text_color": "field_5d4ab40954b40",
        "category_cs_text_color": "#3c304c",
        "_category_cs_text_color": "field_5d4ab5205ffa8",
        "hero_cs_bg_image": 42,
        "_hero_cs_bg_'... (length=6122)
      public 'post_date' => string '2019-08-06 16:41:36' (length=19)
      public 'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_parent' => int 0
      public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
      public 'post_title' => string 'KTURE' (length=5)
      public 'post_type' => string 'work' (length=4)
      public 'slug' => string 'kture' (length=5)
      protected '__type' => null
      public '_edit_lock' => string '1565259680:1' (length=12)
      public '_thumbnail_id' => string '30' (length=2)
      public '_wp_old_slug' => string 'harrods-interior' (length=16)
      public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2019-08-06 16:41:36' (length=19)
      public 'comment_status' => string 'closed' (length=6)
      public 'ping_status' => string 'closed' (length=6)
      public 'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_name' => string 'kture' (length=5)
      public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_modified' => string '2019-08-08 08:06:38' (length=19)
      public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2019-08-08 08:06:38' (length=19)
      public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'guid' => string 'http://simplicitypartners2019.test/?post_type=work&#038;p=29' (length=60)
      public 'menu_order' => int 0
      public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'comment_count' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
      public 'status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
```

As you can see, what I need is the value of "hero_cs_headline" that is inside post_content. Can anyone help me top take this value?

If there is another solution right inside twig file, whould be great as well.

Thanks!

Comment: not sure about timber, but you can always get a certain field by its post id, for example `get_field('field_name', 29);` where 29 is the number i fetched from your code example..?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help much. get_field() doesn't work as it's inside a block.

Comment: not really sure, what you mean by that. you are aware of `parse_blocks`..?

Comment: Yes. I'm using parse_blocks to get all block content and then I'm getting my ACF field from there. But what I'm looking for here is an easiest way to get fields values that are stored inside a block, but I need to get it from another page or template. From my understanding there's no way or native function to get those fields. Thanks by the way!

Comment: you need to share your code, i can't really follow. might have to do with timber/twig, i'm not into that, but lets see..

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a render callback when you create your ACF block:

```
acf_register_block_type( array(
    'name'            => 'example-block',
    'title'           => __( 'Example Block', 'your-text-domain' ),
    'description'     => __( 'A custom example block.', 'your-text-domain' ),
    'render_callback' => 'my_acf_block_render_callback',
    'category'        => 'formatting',
    'icon'            => 'admin-comments',
    'keywords'        => array( 'example' ),
) );
```

Then in that function you call Timber functions like in a page template:

```
function my_acf_block_render_callback( $block, $content = '', $is_preview = false ) {
    $context = Timber::context();

    // Store block values.
    $context['block'] = $block;

    // Store field values.
    $context['fields'] = get_fields();

    // Store $is_preview value.
    $context['is_preview'] = $is_preview;

    // Render the block.
    Timber::render( 'block/example-block.twig', $context );
}
```

After that the block will properly render when output using `{{ post.content }}` or anything else that uses the standard Wordpress filters to display `the_content()`.

More info is available in [Timber's documentation](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/gutenberg/), which is where I got these snippets.

Comment: Additional tip: You can reuse the same function if you use the block's name in the twig file's name, like `Timber::render( 'block/' . $block['name'] . '.twig', $context );`, though you'll have to remove the `acf/` that is automatically prefixed to it.